# UI doesn't change when I setState from active to background of appstate

Tags: react-native

I want to render blur image when app in background state, while render null when app in active state.

I use `setState` to change the state variable `isShow`, looks simple and I ensure that `render` method be executed from `false` to `true` when AppState from `active` to `background`.

but strangely, when I double press home key on my iPhone in background state, I find that my app UI doesn't change.

how should I fix it?

[image]

thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't want to put this as an answer because I don't really haven't done this but...if the app is in the background, I doubt the render method will execute. If you put some logs in the render and componentDidMount are they being fired?

Comment: have you resolved this?